# Read a file from Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, stream, isolatedstorage

I have a folder called `data/` in my project that contains `txt files`.

I configured `Build Action` to `resources` to all files.

I tried these different ways:

#### method 1

```
var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(fName, UriKind.Relative));
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(resource.Stream);
Debug.WriteLine(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
```

#### method 2

```
IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
string[] fileNames = myIsolatedStorage.GetFileNames("*.txt");
```

#### method 3

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
   using (StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fName, FileMode.Open, isf)))
   {
      while (!fileReader.EndOfStream)
      {
        string line = fileReader.ReadLine();
        al.Add(line);
        Debug.WriteLine(line);
      }
   }
}
```

Now, i tried different ways to read files without success, why?
Where is the problem?

What's wrong with these methods?

`fName` is the name of the file.
It's necessary the full path data/filename.txt? It's indifferent...

please help me with this stupid issue,
thanks.

Comment: `NULL` resouce. I can't able to find the files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your 2nd & 3rd approaches are wrong. When you include a text file locally in your app, you can't refer it via the IS. Instead, use this function, it will return the file content if found else it will return `"null"`. It works for me, hope it works for you.

Note, if the file is set as content, the filePath = `"data/filename.txt"` but if it is set as resource it should be referred like this filePath = `"/ProjectName;component/data/filename.txt"`. That may be why your 1st approach might have failed.

```
    private string ReadFile(string filePath)
    {
        //this verse is loaded for the first time so fill it from the text file
        var ResrouceStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(filePath, UriKind.Relative));
        if (ResrouceStream != null)
        {
            Stream myFileStream = ResrouceStream.Stream;
            if (myFileStream.CanRead)
            {
                StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(myFileStream);

                //read the content here
                return myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        return "NULL";
    }
```

Comment: Very well. First method works fine if i set file as `content` instead of `resources`! thanks.

Comment: great! then it was indeed an issue with the filename which you were passing. :)