# Read From Text File in Windows 8 Apps/Windows Phone 8 Apps

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-phone-8, streamreader

If I'm going in the wrong direction, please feel free to give me some guidance!

I'm having trouble understanding the use of streams in the Visual Studio for Windows 8 Apps and Windows 8 Phone Apps environment.

All I want to do is read some text from a file into a string. Here's my simple code that I would use for Visual Studio for Windows Desktop:

```
    Sub ReadFromFileTest()
    Dim FilePath As String = "c:\2012\Projects\VBDesktopTest\Test.txt"
    Dim ReadString As String
    Dim Reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FilePath)

    ReadString = Reader.ReadLine()
    Do Until ReadString Is Nothing
        OutputListBox.Items.Add(ReadString)
        ReadString = Reader.ReadLine()
    Loop
    Reader.Close()
    Reader.Dispose()
    End Sub
```

This same code in Visual Studio for Windows 8 Applications generates an error: "value of type 'string' cannot be converted to 'system.io.stream'".  I've looked through the list of  constructors for the StreamReader class and I see that StreamReader(file name as string) is not supported in ".NET for Windows Store apps".  It seems I need to use the StreamReader(stream) constructor but I can't seem to figure out how to make a make my file into a stream.

My ultimate goal is to create a simple app for Windows Phone 7.1 that looks up and returns information from a list of equipment stored in a text file.  I'm starting with Windows 8 so as not to further confuse myself with the phone emulator.

Answer (score 0):

See I have no idea of Vb .net But I am sharing the c# code (function) that serves the purpose for windows phone

```
 private string ReadFile(string filePath)
{
    //this verse is loaded for the first time so fill it from the text file
    var ResrouceStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(filePath, UriKind.Relative));
    if (ResrouceStream != null)
    {
        Stream myFileStream = ResrouceStream.Stream;
        if (myFileStream.CanRead)
        {
            StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(myFileStream);

            //read the content here
            return myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    return "NULL";
}
```

The answer i took is from this link

[Reading files from stream windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122170/read-a-file-from-windows-phone-7)

Comment: Yes, I keep finding C# code in my searches.  I've tried the vb equivalent to the the code I've found with no resounding success.  This one is new to me using the Application namespace.  I will try it and let you know.