# Application.GetResourceStream can't file the file in the Uri

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to access a .js file.
The file is located inside **Database** folder and named **myfile.js** which is just a JSON formatted text-file.

This is the code I'm using (this is run from **MainPage.xaml.cs**:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("/Database/myfile.js", UriKind.Relative);
var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);

StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(resource.Stream);
string rawData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

It always throw an exception of `NullReferenceException` because the `resource` variable is null.

So, the problem is in the Uri. I tried to use:

```
@"/Database/myfile.js"
"/Database/myfile.js"
"/LQI;component/Database/myfile.js"
```

But it doesn't work.
When I tried to move my file to root directory and replace the Uri string with

```
@"myfile.js"
```

it works! But I don't want that.

I also tried to rename the extension become .txt but nothing.

Please help.
Thanks!

Edit: I set the Build Action to "Content" which is default. I tried to set it to "Resource" but it doesn't work neither.

Edit #2: Okay, I found a clue (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12122332/2649132) that the `LQI;component/Database/myfile.js` only work when I set the item into Resource. And it does work.
But, the question will be still open since I doesn't work when I set the build action to "Content" with regular path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path is a relative path so take the leading "/" off of your path string so it reads "Database/myfile.js" and it should work fine.